# Distance between lines of equations

Tags: line-breaking

```
\documentclass{article}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\label{eq6.1}
    \norm{\lambda_{r,\theta}(z)}_{d+1}^{d+1}:=\sum \limits_{\theta,z}\lambda_{r,\theta}^{d+1}(z)=
\end{align*}    
\begin{align*}
&=\sum \limits_{\theta,z}|\{(u_1,\dots,u_{d+1},v_1,\dots,v_{d+1})\in \mathcal{E}^{2d+2}: u_1-\sqrt{r}\theta v_1=\dots=u_{d+1}-\sqrt{r}\theta v_{d+1}=z\}|=\\
&=\sum \limits_{\theta}|\{(u_1,\dots,u_{d+1},v_1,\dots,v_{d+1})\in \mathcal{E}^{2d+2}: u_i-u_j=\sqrt{r}\theta(v_i-v_j),\ 1\leq i<j\leq d+1\}|.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This code represents the following formula

[image]

I was wondering how to make the distance between the first and second lines smaller?

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: Then please provide proper feedback to the provided answer. He is waiting, see last comment. Maybe you missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you (a) use a single `align*` environment instead of two consecutive `align*` environments and (b) use the `\MoveEqLeft` macro (provided by the `mathtools` package) to "shove" the first line all the way to the left and have the following lines indented relative to the first.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter and \MoveEqLeft macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

%%\usepackage{dsfont}  % \mathds not used in this test document
%%\usepackage{amsmath} % amsmath is loaded automatically by mathtools

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
%\label{eq6.1} %% '\label' is not useful in unnumbered equations
\MoveEqLeft[1]{
\norm[\big]{\lambda_{r,\theta}(z)}_{d+1}^{d+1}
\coloneqq\sum_{\theta,z}\lambda_{r,\theta}^{d+1}(z)} \\
&=\sum_{\theta,z}
  \abs[\big]{ \bigl\{
  (u_1,\dots,u_{d+1},v_1,\dots,v_{d+1}) \in \mathcal{E}^{2d+2}: 
   u_1-\sqrt{r}\theta v_1 = \dots = u_{d+1}-\sqrt{r}\theta v_{d+1} = z
  \bigr\} }\\
&=\sum_{\theta}
  \abs[\big]{ \bigl\{
  (u_1,\dots,u_{d+1},v_1,\dots,v_{d+1}) \in \mathcal{E}^{2d+2}: 
  u_i-u_j=\sqrt{r}\theta(v_i-v_j),\ 
  1\leq i<j\leq d+1
  \bigr\} }\,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, to address the OP's follow-up query: To center the first row while aligning the next two rows on their `=` symbols, I suggest you embed an `align*` environment inside a `gather*` environment:

```
\begin{gather*} 
\norm[\big]{\lambda_{r,\theta}(z)}_{d+1}^{d+1}
\coloneqq\sum_{\theta,z}\lambda_{r,\theta}^{d+1}(z) \\
\begin{align*}
&=\sum_{\theta,z}
  \abs[\big]{ \bigl\{
  (u_1,\dots,u_{d+1},v_1,\dots,v_{d+1}) \in \mathcal{E}^{2d+2}: 
   u_1-\sqrt{r}\theta v_1 = \dots = u_{d+1}-\sqrt{r}\theta v_{d+1} = z
  \bigr\} }\\
&=\sum_{\theta}
  \abs[\big]{ \bigl\{
  (u_1,\dots,u_{d+1},v_1,\dots,v_{d+1}) \in \mathcal{E}^{2d+2}: 
  u_i-u_j=\sqrt{r}\theta(v_i-v_j),\ 
  1\leq i<j\leq d+1
  \bigr\} }\,.
\end{align*}
\end{gather*}
```

---

*Second Addendum*, to address the OP's follow-up query about numbering the three equations in question. To have all three equations numbered, just remove the `gather*` and `align*` environments shown in the initial addendum with `gather` and `align` environments. If you want only some of the three equations in question numbered, add `\notag` (or `\nonumber`) directives as needed. E.g., to make it look like all three equations share a common, single equation number, add `\notag` directives to the first and third equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather} 
  \norm[\big]{\lambda_{r,\theta}(z)}_{d+1}^{d+1}
    \coloneqq\sum_{\theta,z}\lambda_{r,\theta}^{d+1}(z) \\
  \begin{align}
  &=\sum_{\theta,z}
    \abs[\big]{ \bigl\{
    (u_1,\dots,u_{d+1},v_1,\dots,v_{d+1}) \in \mathcal{E}^{2d+2}: 
     u_1-\sqrt{r}\theta v_1 = \dots = u_{d+1}-\sqrt{r}\theta v_{d+1} = z
    \bigr\} }  \\
  &=\sum_{\theta}
    \abs[\big]{ \bigl\{
    (u_1,\dots,u_{d+1},v_1,\dots,v_{d+1}) \in \mathcal{E}^{2d+2}: 
    u_i-u_j=\sqrt{r}\theta(v_i-v_j),\ 
    1\leq i<j\leq d+1
    \bigr\} } \,.
  \end{align}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was wondering is it possible to put the first equation in the center?

Comment: @ZFR - Please see the addendum I posted to address your follow-up question.

Comment: I'd use `aligned` for the nested part, but it's just nitpicking.

Comment: `aligned` fits better. THe last question: how to enumerate this three line equation?

Comment: I mean I refer to these equations and I need to number them.

Comment: @ZFR -- If you remove the `*` from the `gather` and `align` components, all three lines will be numbered.  If you use `aligned`, those lines will be numbered together.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I know this. But I need to assign a single number to these three lines. If I do what you've said, then each line will be assigned some number.

Comment: @ZFR -- Oh, you implied that every line should be numbered.  To get just one number, I would still use `gather`, add `\nonumber` at the end of the first line, then put the two last lines within `aligned` which would produce just a single number.

Comment: @ZFR - Please see the additional addendum I just posted.